# How to change foundation hamburger icon to close icon on click (i.e: mobile menu open)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, hamburger-menu

In foundation menu , the drop-down menu icon is in the button as follows-

`<button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle=""></button>`

[image: Normal menu icon]

```
.menu-icon.dark::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #0a0a0a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 0 #0a0a0a, 0 14px 0 #0a0a0a;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 0 #0a0a0a, 0 14px 0 #0a0a0a;
    content: '';
}
```

How can i make it so that when the mobile menu is open the icon changes to this-

[image]

And vice verse

**[Codepen link to topbar](https://codepen.io/IamManchanda/pen/LymroM)**

Comment: You would have have to listen in on the click event of the menu icon and change it's class to a css rule that draws the pattern you desire. What does the class rule ```.menu-icon.dark``` have? Is it in charge of drawing the menu?

Comment: @tomerpacific the class `.menu-icon.dark` is from foundation which gives the hamburger icon (ie. the 3 lines using the ::after class).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add custom code to achieve this. The solution is that you add an event listener that listens for the user to click on the button. Once clicked, add an active class and style the active class as needed in the stylesheet.

The below code should help.

Add the following code in your style file:

```
//SCSS for Active class

.menu-icon.dark{
   &:after{
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
     &:before{
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
}
.menu-icon.dark.active{
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  &:after{
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background: #0a0a0a;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 12px;
    &:hover{
      opacity: 0.9;
    }

  }
   &:before{
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #0a0a0a;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: rotate(-44deg);
    content: "";
    &:hover{
      opacity: 0.9;
    }
  }
}
```

In the javascript file, add the following code:

```
//Adds active class to the menu icon

$('.menu-icon').on('click', function(){

  $(this).toggleClass("active");

});
```

Comment: We have a toggler component that can be used: https://get.foundation/sites/docs/toggler.html